# Add element in array by button click

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of product cards.

By clicking on the "Add to Cart" button, the element should be added to the array `сartList`, but this does not happen.

I also tried to pass the function to the component, but that didn't lead to anything.

**Shop.jsx:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Instruments.css';
import Cart from '../components/Cart'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import cart from '../img/cart.png';
import data from "../data/data.json";

unction Shop() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState(data);
    const [cartList, setCartList] = useState([]);

    return (
            <div className='shop'>
                <div className='container'>
                        <div className='shop__main-products'>
                            {
                                currentData.filter((el) => {
                                    return value.toLowerCase() === '' ? el : el.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
                                }).map((el, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <Product img={el.img} title={el.title} price={el.price} key={el.id} onClick={() => setCartList([...cartList, el])}/>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Cart active={modalActive} setActive={modalSetActive}/>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
}

export default Shop;
```

**Product.jsx:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Product.css';

function Product({img, title, price, id, type}) {
    return (
                <div className='product' key={id} type={type}>
                    <div className='buy__top'>
                        <div className='product__top-image-background'>
                            <img className='product__top-image' src={img}></img>
                        </div>
                        <h3 className='product__top-title'>{title}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className='product__buy'>
                        <h3 className='product__buy-price'>{price} грн</h3>
                        <button className='product__buy-button'>В корзину</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
}

export default Product;
```

How can you implement adding an object to an array on a button click?

Comment: didn't work out **too** well?!

Comment: You're adding to `cartList` but are always looping over `currentData` therefore it is added but just not shown. However the element your adding is one that is already in the array anyway, so it doesn't really make sense to add it in the first place.

Comment: @leun4m Just fix any spelling errors instead of complain about them

Comment: @mousetail I didn't mean to complain about the spelling. I was referring to an unclear statement. What does not too well mean? Did it work a bit?

Comment: For sure this needs a proper explanation of the exact actual outcome and the difference with the expected outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with how you're passing the onClick function to the Product component. The onClick prop should be passed to the "Add to Cart" button, not the Product component itself. You should change the following line:

```
<Product img={el.img} title={el.title} price={el.price} key={el.id} addToCart={() => setCartList([...cartList, el])}/>
```

And in the Product component, you should add the onClick prop to the "Add to Cart" button:

```
<button className='product__buy-button' onClick={addToCart}>В корзину</button>
```

This way, when the button is clicked, it will call the addToCart function and add the element to the cartList array.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the onClick function to the props of the Product component pass it down the pipe and itll work.

```
function Product({img, title, price, id, type, onClick}) {
return (
            <div className='product' key={id} type={type}>
                <div className='buy__top'>
                    <div className='product__top-image-background'>
                        <img className='product__top-image' src={img}></img>
                    </div>
                    <h3 className='product__top-title'>{title}</h3>
                </div>
                <div className='product__buy'>
                    <h3 className='product__buy-price'>{price} грн</h3>
                    <button className='product__buy-button' onClick={onClick}>В корзину</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}
```